# Null pointer exception in JobIntentService onDestroy

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler, android-8.1-oreo

I am facing issue with JobIntentService in Android 8.1 OS with Signed apk. Where as its working fine with the debug version. Tried with multiple things but couldnt get solution for this. Here is the crash log i got from Crashalytics.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop service com.app.xmpp.XmppService@241c51c6: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService$WorkEnqueuer.serviceProcessingFinished()' on a null object reference

        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopService(ActivityThread.java:3284)

        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:188)

        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1633)

        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)

        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:210)

        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5839)

        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)

        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1113)

        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:879)

     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService$WorkEnqueuer.serviceProcessingFinished()' on a null object reference
        at android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService.onDestroy(JobIntentService.java:479)
        at com.app.xmpp.XmppService.onDestroy(XmppService.java:91)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopService(ActivityThread.java:3265)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:188) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1633) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:210) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5839) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1113)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:879)
```

Help me if anyone faced similar issues with JobIntentService.

Please note this problem cannot be resolved with handling Nullpointer exception, because the NPE is occurring at JobIntentService which is part of Android Framework and we cannot modify it and this is **particularly happening only in Signed APK.**

XMPP Service OnDestroy

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        MyXMPP.instance=null;
        MyXMPP.instanceCreated=false;

        MyXMPP.connection.disconnect();
        xmppConnectionCheckHandler.removeCallbacks(xmppConnectionCheckRunnable);

        System.out.println("--------------Xmpp Service Stopped-----------");
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a NPE. Looks like `WorkEnqueuer` in `XmppService` on line 91 is null. Show us some code, and mark the specific line where exceptions is thrown

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Could you please show your JobIntentService class so we can look into the code? :)

Comment: The WorkerEnqueuer is not part of XmppService, Its part of android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService class from Android Framework

Comment: @Nama Yep, instance of `WorkEnqueuer` is null in `XmppService` on line 91

Comment: Ok, can you please show us what's happening around XmppService.java:91 ?

Comment: @AndreyBusik, Added Xmpp Service code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

From `JobIntentService` class:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mCompatQueue != null) {
        synchronized (mCompatQueue) {
            mDestroyed = true;
            mCompatWorkEnqueuer.serviceProcessingFinished(); //line 479
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "CREATING: " + this);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        mJobImpl = new JobServiceEngineImpl(this);
        mCompatWorkEnqueuer = null;
    } else {
        mJobImpl = null;
        ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(this, this.getClass());
        mCompatWorkEnqueuer = getWorkEnqueuer(this, cn, false, 0);
    }
}
```

Do you perform any manipulation with `mCompatWorkEnqueuer` or `mCompatQueue` in your subclass? Say, like setting it to `null` or `super.onCreate()` invocation?

---

Pay attention that execution of line 479 depends on existence of value of `mCompatQueue`. Also `mCompatWorkEnqueuer` is set to `null` in `onCreate` for API's 26 (8.0) and above

Comment: No.. I am not at all using mCompatWorkEnqueuer  component in my class.. only the JobIntentService is using it seems

Comment: @Nama You can try to move `super.onDestroy()` line at the very bottom of `onDestroy()` method

Comment: @Nama You don't set the value of mCompatQueue too?

Comment: I've tried moving it to bottom. It didnt work. Yes.. no need to set value of mCompatQueue.  Just need to call : 

enqueueWork(context, XmppService.class, JOB_ID, work);